# How do you make a variable size div?

Tags: html, css

How do I make a div that has a variable width? So I want a div to span a certain width inside a container and if there is another element in it, the div will automatically fill a portion of the of the width.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? e.g, add a picture of your desired result, or some code?

Answer (score 2):

Don't give the div a width and it will fill 100% of the horizontal space. Add margins to it (as either % or px) and it will shrink accordingly.

It sounds like you may be asking how to have something inside the div force it to grow wider with its content. I don't think that's possible without javascript.

Comment: When you talk about forcing the div to grow wider with its content, would the "[shrinkwrapping](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap)" techniques do what you meant in CSS? It's hard to talk about this without pictures! :)

Comment: No, I think you know what I am asking but its not working for some reason. I want the div to fill 100% of the horizontal space if there is nothing else beside the div.

Comment: @Matt Thanks  :) "shrinkwrapping" is the name i couldn't think of.

Comment: @bhavinp Have you set the div to float? If you set it to float: left or right it will get confused and no longer fill 100% of the width. Make sure it's not. Also check the padding on the containing div. If neither of those I think we need to see an example.